# Windows phone 7 Listbox ArrangeOverride can't work?

Tags: windows-phone-7, silverlight-4.0

I override listbox's ArrangeOverride method  want to show itemSource like this:
(i collcation DependencyObject on PrepareContainerForItemOverride method)

1 2 3 4
5 6 7 8
.....
......100

but when i scroll the scrollbar   the array change like this:

1
2
3
4
5
......
100

```cs
protected override Size ArrangeOverride(Size finalSize)
    {
        if (this._ItemsDictionary.Count <= 0)
        {
            return base.ArrangeOverride(finalSize);
        }
        base.ArrangeOverride(finalSize);
        finalSize = this.MeasureOverride(_availableSize);

        double xMemory = 0;
        double yMemory = 0;
        double maxBoderWidth = 0;
        double maxHeight = 0;

        foreach (FrameworkElement element in _ItemsDictionary.Values)
        {
            if (xMemory + element.DesiredSize.Width <= finalSize.Width)
            {
                element.Arrange(new Rect(xMemory, yMemory, element.DesiredSize.Width, element.DesiredSize.Height));
                xMemory += element.DesiredSize.Width;
                maxHeight = Math.Max(element.DesiredSize.Height, maxHeight);
            }
            else
            {
                yMemory += maxHeight;
                maxBoderWidth = Math.Max(maxBoderWidth, xMemory);
                xMemory = 0;
                maxHeight = 0;

                element.Arrange(new Rect(xMemory, yMemory, element.DesiredSize.Width, element.DesiredSize.Height));
                xMemory += element.DesiredSize.Width;
                maxHeight = Math.Max(element.DesiredSize.Height, maxHeight);
            }
        }
        return finalSize;
    }

    protected override void PrepareContainerForItemOverride(DependencyObject element, object item)
    {
        base.PrepareContainerForItemOverride(element, item);
        FrameworkElement fElement = element as FrameworkElement;
        if (!_ItemsDictionary.ContainsKey(item))
        {
            _ItemsDictionary.Add(item, fElement);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hi, consider posting some of your Xaml / C# code to assist people in answering your question

Answer (score 2):

I may be wrong. But it seems that your base class is **ItemsPresenter** (or something inherited from it like **ListBox**). It's not a good idia. Becouse EACH **ItemsPresenter** have it's own **ItemsPanel**! And Silverlight use this panel for layouting items. So **ItemsPresenter** can't layout it's own items directly, only trou **ItemsPanel** panel.

1) I recomend you to use **WrapPanel** (that is part of Silverlight SDK) so you have it for free, i think this is what you want. Just replace ListBox.ItemsPanel property with **WrapPanel** and you going to get result that you wanted

2) If you want create your own pannel you better create new class and inherit it from Panel

```
public class SomeNewPanel: Panel
{
    protected override System.Windows.Size MeasureOverride(System.Windows.Size availableSize)
    {
        //you can add here your custom measure logic
        return base.MeasureOverride(availableSize);
    }

    protected override System.Windows.Size ArrangeOverride(System.Windows.Size finalSize)
    {
        //you can add here your custom arrange logic
        return base.ArrangeOverride(finalSize);
    }
}
```

and then use it in ListBox like this.

```
<Page x:Class="SilverlightApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    <!--Don't forget to add namespace of your newly created panel-->
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SilverlightApplication1"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <ListBox x:Name="listBox1" ItemsSource="{Binding SomeItemSource}">
        <!--ItemPanel property set or get Panel that-->
        <!--will be used for layouting items-->
        <ListBox.ItemsPanel>

            <!--Here you and your newly created panle-->
            <local:SomeNewPanel/>

        </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
    </ListBox>
</Grid>
</Page>
```

Comment: `<eCtrl:VerticalShadowListBox.ItemsPanel>
                        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            <toolkit:WrapPanel />
                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    </eCtrl:VerticalShadowListBox.ItemsPanel>`